# In XCODE / Swift, how can I create a single function which can be called from various view controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, global

I would like to implement a set of functions and that they be called by various view controllers in my app.

Whats the best approach for this?

An example of a function to be used throughout the app is this one which returns a formatted Float as a string:

```
func roundAndFormatFloat(floatToReturn : Float, numDecimalPlaces: Int) -> String{

    let formattedNumber = String(format: "%.\(numDecimalPlaces)f", floatToReturn)
    return formattedNumber

}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague - give some examples about what the functions should do. Should they work with the data contained/handled by the view controller? Or by its views?

Comment: Have you considered class methods? Or a singleton?

Comment: I've updated the question to include an example function which needs used in various views throughout the app Antonio. Clafou, I've never heard of a singleton but I could implement the function in a class and have the class return the floats already formatted. Good idea!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suggest creating a new file called Util.swift, and paste that function into that file. This is what Util.swift would look like:

```
import UIKit

func roundAndFormatFloat(floatToReturn : Float, numDecimalPlaces: Int) -> String{

    let formattedNumber = String(format: "%.\(numDecimalPlaces)f", floatToReturn)
    return formattedNumber

}
```

You can place other functions and constants you need in Util.swift. To call it in your view controller, you do this:

```
var str = roundAndFormatFloat(float, numDecimalPlaces: decimalPlaces)
```

Here is another option. Create another class called Util, and put this function in there as a class function:

```
import UIKit

class Util{
    class func roundAndFormatFloat(floatToReturn : Float, numDecimalPlaces: Int) -> String{

        let formattedNumber = String(format: "%.\(numDecimalPlaces)f", floatToReturn)
        return formattedNumber

    }
}
```

Calling it would look like this:

```
var str = Util.roundAndFormatFloat(float, numDecimalPlaces: decimalPlaces)
```

You can add other class methods here that you need to use globally. Note that you cannot create globally available variables or constants this, as class variables and constants have not been implemented yet in Swift.

Comment: Thats fantastic. I was hoping to be able to create a separate file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked perfect for me, and I gave it a bump. But I was wondering what Util is supposed to stand for? My thought was Utility?

Comment: Yes, or Utilities.

Comment: Does the first option still work with Swift 3?  It appears not to for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Swift way is to extend `UIViewController` and add your functions there.

Swift 3 Example:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func roundAndFormatFloat(floatToReturn : Float, numDecimalPlaces: Int) -> String{
        let formattedNumber = String(format: "%.\(numDecimalPlaces)f", floatToReturn)

        return formattedNumber
    }

    func foo() -> String {
        return "foo"
    }

}
```

Comment: Extensions worked the best for my program! Great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Util class in Swift:

1. Create new file with name Util
2. Create a class functions : **class func funtionname:() -> {}**

Exmaple:

import UIKit
        import Foundation

```
    class Util: NSObject {


        //MARK: - SET USER LOGGED IN
        class func set_IsUserLoggedIn(state : Bool) {
            var userloggedin:     UserDefaults?
            userloggedin        = UserDefaults.standard
            userloggedin?.set(state, forKey: "IS_USER_LOGGED_IN")
        }


        //MARK: - GET USER LOGGED IN
        class func get_IsUserLoggedIn() -> Bool {

            var userloggedin:     UserDefaults?
            userloggedin        = UserDefaults.standard

            var checkUser:Bool? = false
            checkUser           = userloggedin?.bool(forKey: "IS_USER_LOGGED_IN")

            return checkUser!
        }



    }
```

You can call the Util function in Any Class file
like:

```
 if Util.get_IsUserLoggedIn(){
        print("User is logged in")

    }
    else{
        print("User is not logged in")
    }
```